# No display with message:"Guest has not initialized the display (yet)." when I try to run Android on qemu

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, boot

I just try to run android on qemu. I work on an Ubuntu 16.04 with `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790` CPU.

I sync and compile `android-6.0.1_r1` into `aosp_arm-eng`. 
I sync and compile `qemu 2.9.91` with arm platform.

Then, I try to do my job by the following shell code:

```
    ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH=${ANDROID_PATH}/out/target/product/generic
    QEMU_ARCH="arm"
    QEMU_OPTS="-cpu cortex-a15 -machine type=virt"
    KERNEL_CMDLINE='console=ttyAMA0,38400 earlycon=pl011,0x09000000 debug nosmp drm.debug=0x0 rootwait androidboot.selinux=permissive'
    LINUX_PATH=${ANDROID_PATH}/prebuilts/qemu-kernel
    KERNEL=${LINUX_PATH}/arm/kernel-qemu-armv7

    ${QEMU_PATH}/${QEMU_ARCH}-softmmu/qemu-system-${QEMU_ARCH} \
    ${QEMU_OPTS} \
    -append "${KERNEL_CMDLINE}" \
    -m 1024 \
    -serial mon:stdio \
    -kernel ${KERNEL} \
    -initrd ${ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH}/ramdisk.img \
    -drive index=0,if=none,id=system,format=raw,file=${ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH}/system.img \
    -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system \
    -drive index=1,if=none,id=cache,format=raw,file=${ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH}/cache.img \
    -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache \
    -drive index=2,if=none,id=userdata,format=raw,file=${ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH}/userdata.img \
    -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata \
    -netdev user,id=mynet,hostfwd=tcp::5550-:5555 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet \
    -display gtk,gl=on \
    -device virtio-gpu-pci,virgl \
    -device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci \
    -device sdhci-pci \
    -d guest_errors \
    $*
```

Then I get the message: "Guest has not initialized the display (yet)" on qemu window as the following picture:
[image]

The question may is because that the kernel and the options is not matched.

So first(1) I check the images.
I run the emulator with the above images and path.
The emulator is based on qemu and got from Android source code.
I run the emulator with the following code and it work.

```
EMULATOR_PATH=${ANDROID_PATH}/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64
${EMULATOR_PATH}/emulator \
    -kernel ${KERNEL} \
    -ramdisk ${ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH}/ramdisk.img \
    -system ${ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH}/system.img \
    -data ${ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH}/userdata.img \
-sysdir ${ANDROID_IMAGE_PATH} \
-memory 512 \
    -partition-size 1024
```

[image]

Now, there may has something wrong in the options with qemu. 
So could someone tell me the useful machine type or some other option?

I'll thank you very much if you could give me some help (⊙o⊙)

Comment: I don't understand your question. It seem that QEMU is running just fine, so what is the problem?

Comment: @not2qubit it's just Android emu which is running fine. the options are partially different.

Answer (score 0):

try `-display gtk,gl=off` to disable the GL display driver, which possibly may vary.

or `-nographic`, in order to run headless.

see https://www.linux-kvm.org/images/b/b2/01x10b-QEMUGfraphics.pdf