# "Guest has not initialized the display yet" (Raspberry Pie on QEMU)

Tags: android, emulation, qemu

I am a newbie student.
I am trying to run a Raspberry Pi Emulator on QEMU.
PC specs are Intel q8200, quad-core 2,4 GHz, Nvidia GeForce 1 GB. 4GB RAM
https://prnt.sc/uvpi0h

1. The above image is where you can see the commands and the state of the running QEMU. And other things.
   https://prnt.sc/uvplco
2. This is in my download folder for this project.

I've tried to run different kernels (stretch and booster), even different Pi Emulator images, but the same mistake.
I've seen that in some solutions, a guy said that he hadn't included his BIOS in commands and that helped him, but I dunno how to include or specify BIOS in CMP.
All files inside the Qemu folder (images and kernel) are matching the start.bat commands folder, so that is all ok.
I've tried to do all of that through this channel instructions, but since it is outdated, I've just downloaded the latest software.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiQX0YXYuqU&t=138s&ab_channel=TechWizTime

What could be the solution and what is the problem?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Windows10 pro is the OS
UPDATE 1: Added this command: -boot no -display gtk,gl=of
still the same.
UPDATE 2:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.12-jessie -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb \
-no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
-redir tcp:5022::22 \
-hda 2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie-lite.img
```

I've used this to solve the problem. Although it is another version of the Raspberry Pi, for my needs it is not relevant now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809557/no-display-with-messageguest-has-not-initialized-the-display-yet-when-i-tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important error message in the output is the one from the guest kernel which reads:

```
Error: unrecognized/unsupported machine ID (r1 = 0x00000183)
```

and then lists the machine types it is capable of booting on. (As a side note, providing error messages as screenshot images is rather awkward -- copying the text itself into the question makes it searchable and copyable.)

It looks like you're trying to boot a guest kernel which requires a device tree, but you haven't passed it a device tree. You need to give QEMU also a -dtb option whose argument is the correct dtb for this kernel and for the machine type ('versatilepb') that you are running it on.

Comment: Thank you. And for the copying of the text. I will keep in mind.
Ok, I solved it with - I'll post it in edit. I've just used another command, very similar.